# Android, List events from specific calendar (on Phone (?))

Tags: android, events, calendar

I want to show a ListView with the events of the current day from a specific calendar. The calendar is originally fetched from a .ical file and synchronized into my google account. And yes, I've searched.
Should I go with the content:// stuff?

Im using Android 2.2 and above.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the Google Calendar API functions. On the surface it seems like tons of work, however you are mostly importing (Build Path) their jar files and making the appropriate imports and method calls.

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/getting_started.html

This turns into HTTP requests and the like, which implies you must always be connected to the network (I'm not a fan of that).

Officially supported or not, I am working on an application that is working with the local phone calendar database and doing what I need to do there (yes, the content:// URI stuff you mentioned above).

Either way, you can do what you are needing to do as your application seems simple enough. Most people, and rightfully so, will tell you to use the Google Calendar API imports/calls because it is supported functionality that does not rely on how the device manufacturer chose to implement the back end content provider. Although every phone I have tested uses "content://com.android.calendar/events" as the URI, that does not mean that it will always work as that can change (and has in the past) based on the version of Android running on the device.

- Android 2.1 and before:  content://calendar/calendars
- Android 2.2 - 2.3:  content://com.android.calendar/calendars